# Ajax call failing to get the return message from web api service

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am making a simple ajax call to the web api service that serves an authentication routine.
My problem is the ajax call can make a request to the service but errors out once the service returns a boolean value.

**WHAT I WANT:**

All i want to do is check if the returned boolean is true or false. If true i want to redirect the user to another page.
Could somebody please help me out on this?

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {   
        var name = $(userNameTextBox).val);          
        var pass = $(passwordTextBox).val();
        if (name.length == 0 || pass.length == 0) {
            alert("Please enter your credentials");
        }
        else {
             $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:50503/api/Authentication/Authenticate",
                data: { userName: name, passWord: pass },
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (msg) {

                    alert(msg);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("Error Message: "+msg);
                }                  
            });

        }//end of else
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my webapi service

```
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Authentication/Authenticate")]
    public bool Authenticate(string userName,string passWord)
    {
        if (userName.ToLower().Equals("username") && passWord.ToLower().Equals("password"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the error ?

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: Maybe it's not returning valid JSON?

Comment: your `dataType` is `json`. If you only return a boolean, you dont need to return a `json`, i think.

Comment: There isnt any code in your success block ,you need to add the code there to redirect the user depending on the value that is returned from server(true/false)

Comment: Hi All The problem is i just get the error message saying "Request Message: Error" Thats all. The Request.done method doesn't have any implementation at the moment because the code flow is not even reaching there at the moment. Is not possible for webapi to return boolean? or am i missing some standard procedure here?

Comment: did you try to just `echo` the username, to make sure you reach the right `route` ?

Comment: How do you receive this error message? Your fail callback  prints "Request Failed", so that doesn't seem to be the source.

Comment: @MamaWalter as i said. i placed the debugger on server side code so it has reached the right route. but the route from server to the client seems to be a problem. In the response section all i am seeing is an empty page

Comment: @aknuds1 which source are you referring to?

Comment: I mean, where is your "Request Message: Error" caught in JavaScript? It doesn't seem to be your fail callback, since it emits a different error message although I could be wrong.

Comment: I have updated the code. still it hits the error section but i can see it nicely makes the call to the service passing the appropriate username and password. its just that when the service returns the boolean the client cannot interpret the response

Comment: Try debugging in Chrome dev tools, and see if the request succeeds or fails. Also, there must be a more specific error message?

Comment: I am using fiddler. I see no error message. all i see is 200 status code. which means calls are ok

Comment: And JSON is sent in the response? Does it work if you drop the `dataType` option from the $.ajax call?

Comment: Yes i dropped but it doesn't make any difference. strange  Do we have to manually set the request host header as well?

Comment: You should try to get a more descriptive error message; I've reproduced your code with Web API 1/jQuery 1.9. and it works without a hitch. You could for instance set a debugger breakpoint within your error callback, and figure out from the stacktrace what causes the error.

Comment: that is where i am struggling, if your ajax call works then could you please post that code here. May be i am missing something that you havent.

Comment: I've added my test code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replace your ajax call by this maybe, remove the `dataType`:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:50503/api/Authentication/Authenticate",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { userName: userName, passWord: passWord }
});
request.done(function (msg) {
   //check the boolean and redirect user to another page.
   if(msg) window.location.href = "http://nextpage.com";
});
```

i also change the method to `POST`. More appropriate in your case.

Comment: the request.done method doesn't execute at the moment cause the flow directly errors out after making the call

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, put a debugger breakpoint (e.g., via the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) directive in your error callback to `$.ajax` and run your code in the browser's debugger (i.e. Chrome dev tools). Then, after the breakpoint is hit, you should be able to determine (by walking the stack) why the error callback is invoked.

## My Test

I've tried to reproduce your case, and for me it doesn't fail. I've defined a test controller in the following way:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            return username == "user" && password == "pass";
        }
    }
}
```

And I make an AJAX call to it from JavaScript like so:

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://localhost:59900/api/test', type: 'get', dataType: 'json', cache: false, data: { userName: 'user', passWord: 'pass' }}).done(function () {console.log("Success", arguments);}).fail(function () { console.log("Error", arguments); });
```

The AJAX call invokes the success callback (`done`) with `true` as its result, so no issues at all.

## Parser Error

It appears that jQuery can't parse the JSON sent from Web API (`true`). To return valid JSON, return an object of the following type from your controller:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool Result { get;set; }
}
```

This should result in the following JSON being sent to your client:

```
{ "Result": true }
```

Updated controller:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public Result Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            return new Result { Result = username == "user" && password == "pass" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the url:'http://localhost:59900/api/test' section don't you need Authenticate action as well?

Comment: @Sike12 No, because the route is just the controller (api/<controller>). That's the standard Web API routing scheme.

Comment: Just to mention i am using webapi2. that might be the reason why its not working for me

Comment: @Sike12 Yeah I noticed, but I would imagine that Web API 2 is backwards compatible. Try to copy my TestController verbatim and see how that works.

Comment: I copied all your code onto mine and when i run it i get Error [Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error", more...}, "error", ""]

Comment: @Sike12 Interesting. You're sure the controller returns 200 OK? Can you expand the error response in Chrome dev tools console to get more details? It's imperative to find out where the error originates.

Comment: ok fiddler and firebug both failed.   but using chrome i was able to see this ...event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. browserLink:37
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50503/api/test?userName=user&passWord=pass&_=1393703205197. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49354' is therefore not allowed access. login:1
Error 
[Object, "error", ""]

Comment: @Sike12 Not sure if the error you're seeing is related, it looks like a BrowserLink issue, which can be ignored. How about the request (in the Network pane of dev tools), does that result in 200 OK? Regarding the Error line, please expand the first argument ("Object") in the console to see its details.

Comment: Error 
[Object, "parsererror", Error]
0: Object
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "success"
success: function () {

Comment: Also in addition to the above message. It seems like the server cannot find the client when it tries to return the message.    Here is the log from the network pane of dev tools.Request URL:http://localhost:49354/060bc4b0b3174c1096782c1cf6a012ca/arterySignalR/ping?requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49354%2FLogin&browserName=Chrome&_=1393704204602
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: @Sike12 Just ignore the request that returns 404, it's a BrowserLink request generated by Visual Studio (you can tell by the arterySignalR part).

Comment: @Sike12: The second argument to the error callback says "parsererror", so probably you must return valid JSON from Web API. See my updated answer for a possible solution.

Comment: still getting this error in the console. "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."  How can i set this header in the ajax call?

Comment: @Sike12 Like I said before, you can ignore that error because it's caused by a BrowserLink request. I get those errors too, they don't matter. Try my suggested solution, and see if that changes things.

Comment: Yes i did that. now i am getting the same parser error

Comment: @Sike12 That is very strange. Copy the JSON from the server's response and validate it at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: this is the exact error message from the console.Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : test:1
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, 
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {

pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "success"

Comment: @Sike12 Why are you getting a SyntaxError now? You never mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. i ran the previous version accidentally. i am getting server response as 
{ "Result": true } but the client still is giving parser error

Comment: the response {"result":true}. the client is not liking this result for some reason even though it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Sike12 Does the response contain the header `Content-Type:application/json`? I'm really unsure why valid JSON would give a parser error.

Comment: We are returning a JsonResult custom built object so it will never be json type. Can't we convert it to proper json format before sending it from the server

Comment: @Sike12 No idea what you mean. Web API is supposed to return a standard JSON response to the client. It certainly works for me.

Comment: i am trying to use the return type as System.web.mvc.jsonResult. I don't why it is so unlucky day for me.

Comment: @Sike12 Where do you use System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult? Try to not use that, it has nothing to do with Web API to my knowledge.

Comment: ok the error message is this ...Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : test:1.   When i click on test:1 i get this ...{"Result":false}. I don't see why the ajax call is erroring out on this response

Comment: @Sike12 It depends if the server is sending the header `Content-Type:application/json` with the response to the client. If you're using JsonResult that might mess things up.

Comment: I switched back to what you recommended  but i am still getting the Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token: test:1

Comment: @Sike12 Well, check the response header `Content-Type:application/json`. There must be a reason why valid JSON can't be parsed.

Comment: the response header is Content-Type:application/json. There is no parsing error now. All i am getting is the Uncaught Syntax Error thingy.

Comment: @Sike12 Ah, syntax. Are you using my JavaScript code or yours? If you're using mine, try yours and vice versa. See if the syntax error disappears.

Comment: I tried both and they giving same syntax error. I'll Continue in the morning :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use (worked for me, check responseJSON.Message of first parameter object):

```
$.post(url, jsonData).
done(function (data) {}).
fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
   alert("Error " + err + ". " + xhr.responseJSON.Message);
});
```